# Why context update another entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a logger service which I use to add the actions into a table, for each endpoint. For an unknown reason, when I use `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` in this service, it will update another table (with a nested object for required entity).

controller:

```
var model = await teamsService.GetTeamData("team_url");
await eventsLogger.LogInfo("className", "actionName", $"Get team data by url {name}", user);

return Ok(model);

// I don't want to wait for logger response, but I get another error if I don't use async here 
// (anyway is not the subject)
// _ = eventsLogger.LogInfo("className", "actionName", $"Get team data by url {name}", user);
```

TeamsService GetData() method

```
var team = await dataContext.Teams.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UrlPath == urlPath);

team.Views += 1;
dataContext.Update(team);
await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

var performances = await dataContext.Performances
   .Where(x => x.TeamId == team.Id)
   .ToListAsync();

// return team and performances as nested responses;
```

Logs Service Log method

```
 var event = new Event() { ... params };
 dataContext.Add(event);
 await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // AT THIS MOMENT IS THE PROBLEM
```

both services are declared as Scoped inside of `Startup.cs` (also tried to use it as Transient)

Startup services

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
  options.UseSqlServer(
     Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnection"),
     sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(120)
  );
});
services.AddScoped<IEventsLogger, EventsLogger>();
services.AddScoped<ITeamsService, TeamsService>();
```

If I change the lines in controller method, to log first, I'll avoid this behavior. But I don't want this. I need to understand why the **performances entities** are modified (only 2 fields from the entity - a 'Year' string field and a 'Count' int field)

```
// this will work
await eventsLogger.LogInfo("className", "actionName", $"Get team data by url {name}", user);
var model = await teamsService.GetTeamData("team_url");
return Ok(model);
```

It looks like different contexts are being used, but the data is being reset, not updated to an older version, as it should be if one context is older than another.

Also, I removed the `team.Views += 1` line, this is happening only when I save the log.

thx

Comment: The DbContext is registered as scoped, and the scope lasts for the entire request. This means that in your case you're modifying entity properties, which will be persisted once your event service calls SaveChanges (). The solution is to not do that, or to map to models instead of entities and operate on those, or to not use EF for mere insertion of data, or, or, or...

Comment: So if I use `Select` with `DTO`s in EF query (or `AutoMapper`), instead of working directly with the entities, can it solve this problem? To be honest, I already use it for other entities, but here, for fast development I worked directly with the entities (it's a personal project). // each "transaction/request" should use `SaveChangesAsync` only once ?!

Comment: Yes, you were right. If I use a DTO, the problem no longer occurs